# Prove that for all $a\in \mathbb Z$, $a>2 \Rightarrow a \nmid b$ or $a \nmid (b +1)$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that for all $a\in \mathbb Z$,  $a>2 \Rightarrow a \nmid b$ or $a \nmid (b +1)$

I understand direct proof techniques and contrapositive proofs but I'm stumped on how to go about this.

Comment: Have you learned proof by contradiction yet? That would be the easiest way to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a bunch of notation, let's say what it means: It means that if $a$ is an integer larger than $2$, then $a$ can't divide both $b$ and $b + 1$.

As a hint, suppose that $a | b$ and $a | b + 1$. Then it's also true that $a$ must divide the difference, $(b + 1) - b = 1$, so what can $a$ possibly be?

Comment: That's not quite what it means; the statement says that if $a$ is an integer larger than $2$, then there are integers $b$ such that $a$ divides _neither_ $b$ nor $b+1$. No integer greater than $1$ divides both $b$ and $b+1$.

Comment: @user98602 No, it doesn't. It says $(a\nmid b)\vee (a\nmid b+1)$, which is the same as $\neg (a\mid b)\vee \neg(a\mid b+1)$, which is the same as $\neg ((a\mid b)\wedge (a\mid b+1))$ by de Morgan's laws. And BTW since $b$ is not bound by any quantifier, it's common to assume that it's arbitrary, i.e. $\forall b \in \mathbb{Z} \dots$, and not $\exists b \in \mathbb{Z} \dots$ like you did.